# Nested subscriptions anti-pattern with loader logic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following code, wherein I am pulling data from a variety of sources and setting a loaded flag once it is done. At the moment however, it is rather cumbersome to maintain. How can I go about fixing it?

```
  constructor(
    private courseContentFacade: CourseContentFacade,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
    this.courseContentFacade
      .getUnsplashPhotos()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe((unsplashPhotos) => {
        this.unsplashPhotosLoaded = false;
        if (unsplashPhotos) {
          this.parseUnsplashPhotos(unsplashPhotos);
        }
        this.courseContentFacade
          .getPexelsPhotos()
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
          .subscribe((pexelsPhotos) => {
            this.unsplashPhotosLoaded = false;
            if (pexelsPhotos) {
              this.parsePexelsPhotos(pexelsPhotos);
            }
            setTimeout(
              () => {
                this.courseMediaItemsLoaded = true;
                this.pexelsPhotosLoaded = true;
                this.unsplashPhotosLoaded = true;
              },
              environment.production ? 2500 : 1000
            );
          });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Maybe merge is an option here? https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge

Comment: why do you needs the flags to be in settimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I might rework this to be a bit more idiomatic RxJS. This code still leans heavily on the use of global state.

The less your application as a whole requires mutable global state, the easier it will be to maintain and extend. This is 5x - 10x as true when it comes to RxJS.

Even so, using higher-order operators (in this case mergeMap) does a lot to cut down on the nesting and complexity created here :)

```ts
constructor(
  private courseContentFacade: CourseContentFacade,
  private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) {

  this.courseContentFacade.getUnsplashPhotos().pipe(

    tap(_ => this.unsplashPhotosLoaded = false),
    tap(unsplashPhotos => {
      if (unsplashPhotos) {
        this.parseUnsplashPhotos(unsplashPhotos);
      }
    }),

    mergeMap(_ => this.courseContentFacade.getPexelsPhotos()),
    tap(_ => this.pexelsPhotosLoaded = false),
    tap(pexelsPhotos => {
      if(pexelsPhotos) {
        this.parsePexelsPhotos(pexelsPhotos);
      }
    }),

    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
    delay(environment.production ? 2500 : 1000)
    

  ).subscribe(_ => {
    this.courseMediaItemsLoaded = true;
    this.pexelsPhotosLoaded = true;
    this.unsplashPhotosLoaded = true;
  });
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is so much easier to follow. However, I just wanted to ask, why you have `subscribe((unsplashPhotos)` right at the end?

Comment: @methuselah Hey, that's just because I didn't proof-read my work! The subscription is being passed `pexelsPhotos,` but we can actually ignore that value as it's never used. I've updated the answer.